# JSON in Browser cookie

Tags: json, cookies

I'm not sure whether this problem is discussed before but I want o store a javascript object in cookie through javascript.

Basically my problem is I've a html form with few input fields. I want to take input from the fields and store the same values in a javascript object. This javascript object is only accessible until I'm in this page. But once I go to another page, my javascript object becomes null/undefined. So I thought I can store the javascript object somewhere from where I can get back the values I entered from the input fields. But I don't know how I should be able to do this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Rupam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie is the way to go.
You can do something like :

1. Add the plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
2. Setting a cookie:

   $.cookie("CookieName","CookieValue");
3. Clearing the cookie:

   $.removeCookie("CookieName");
4. Accessing the value in the cookie:

   var temp = $.cookie("CookieName");

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to use a dedicated persistant storage lib such as : http://brian.io/lawnchair/ It does exactly what you are looking for (and even more).